# Change special mark colour in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I would like to change color of single '=' (equality sign) but leave the multi marks '==' or '===' alone.

Same with '!' mark, but I don't want to change '!=' or similar.

How to do that? I'm fighting with (Adaptive.sublime.color.scheme):

```
        {
        "name": "Keyword",
        "scope": "keyword - (source.c keyword.operator | source.c++ keyword.operator | source.objc keyword.operator | source.objc++ keyword.operator), keyword.operator.word",
        "foreground": "var(green)" // if, else, new, ,in, return, '=', '+', '&', '|', '!=', etc.
    },
```

to no avail. Is there option to change single special mark color?

Comment: I don't mean to turn you away from sublime, but take a look at VS Code. Sublime hasn't been updated since May 2018, and a lot of plugins and such are losing support etc.

Comment: Everyone is free to use whatever tools work best for them, but please note that the assertion that Sublime has not been updated since May 2018 is [patently false](https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev).

Comment: @lolrj11 you can easily achieve altering the color for `==` but probably not `!`. The answer depends on what language you're using, though.

Comment: I'm using mainly JS.